# How to encode a cookie data in jsp and decode it in php?

Tags: java, php, jsp, cookies, encode

We have created a cookie like below

```
Cookie userNamecookie = new Cookie ("username", URLEncoder.encode(snUser.getUsername(), "UTF-8"));
userNamecookie.setPath("/");
userNamecookie.setMaxAge(60);
response.addCookie(userNamecookie);
```

but i want to create cookie with encoded data and that has to be decode in php. Can any one please help me.

Comment: How about PHPs `url_decode()` function?

Comment: Thanks TiMESPLiNTER. Actually my data is not yet encoded. above code is not working to encode data.

Comment: You have a single server with both php and Java? Why?

Comment: Why does it not work @venu Any exceptions?

Comment: yes both are working in the same server @Elliott Frisch.

Comment: No Exception, i am seeing normal string cookie data in browser setting but i am expecting encoded data @TiMESPLiNTER.

Comment: @venu I would expect that it's being decoded when you get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Java's `URLEncoder.encode()` uses the same encoding standards as PHP's `urlencode()` function.

Therefore, to decode a string that has been encoded using Java's `URLEncoder.encode()`, you can use PHP's [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function.

e.g.

```
$username_encoded = $_COOKIE["username"];
$username_decoded = urldecode($username_encoded);
```